# How can I call a method from .bash_profile in CodeKit Hooks

Tags: bash, codekit

Running on a Mac.
On CodeKit, in the Hooks...
Can I call a method defined in my `.bash_profile`?

In my `.bash_profile` I have created

```
deployLocal(){//do something}
```

In CodeKit, there is an option in hooks to run a bin/bash command upon a certain action.

If I paste the entire content of deployLocal inside the hook it runs.

QUESTION: How can I simply call that method rather than having to paste it in?

Comment: The trivial solution is to save it as an external script in you `PATH` instead of embedding it in your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Your `.bash_profile` should only be read by the system when the shell is invoked as an interactive login shell (or for a non-interactive shell if the `--login` option is given). You should not be trying to invoke parts of it otherwise. Save whatever part you need as a separate script, make it executable, and call that from CodeKit.

Comment: this is a reusable script that I will sometimes run from the terminal. I want CodeKit to run the same script when I save files. (script copies files to a docker folder and does several other things with them). I don't really want two copies of the same script. So keeping it in the bashprofile seems wise.